# What is the difference between * and NULL when selecting from a table in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL, and I wasn't able to find a resource describing the difference between * and NULL when selecting from a table.

For example:

```
SELECT null, null, *, null FROM items
```

Is that any different than:

```
SELECT null, null, null, null FROM items
```

and is this any different than:

```
SELECT * FROM items
```

if there were only four columns to begin with?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using??

Comment: I don't know, it's not my server

Comment: I don't mean any offense, but you should probably find a tutorial on SQL. This is an extremely basic question, and if you need to ask it you're going to need to learn a lot to accomplish anything. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, I'm using this book http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/516GF07TZHL.jpg . I do try to consult other resources before asking. Please list a resource that explains this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that book (a link to the book page instead of it's cover image would have been more useful), but if it doesn't explain the difference between `SELECT NULL` and `SELECT *`, you should probably find a different book. I'd suspect it does, though, because a search for that book on Amazon shows 4 stars (5 for the next edition). A test would have shown the difference, though. Remember that, unlike other types of SQL statement, a `SELECT` can't do damage. `SELECT * FROM items` and `SELECT NULL from items` would have shown you the difference. :-)

Comment: There's a good online book for learning SQL here http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OF course there is.

The first one:

```
SELECT null, null, null, null FROM items
```

Will select four columns with `NULL` values in each, ***whatever the values and the columns in this table `items`***. But the number of rows returned will equal to the number of rows in the `items` table, if you have n rows in the `items` table, it will return n rows with all the columns have `NULL` values.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99665/1)

---

**However:**

```
SELECT * FROM items
```

Will select all the columns with all the values in this table `items`.

Se they are totally different.

In your case since there are only four columns, the first one will ***always*** select four `NULL` columns, where is the second one will select them with the values that contain.

Comment: But I said what if there are only 4 columns in the table... are they still going to give different results?

Comment: @ChrisHarris - The first one will ***always*** select four nullable columns with one one `NULL` value in each, however the second one select the columns with all the values in these columns.

Comment: You shouldn't call them "nullable columns", implying that they contains values but their underlying table allows NULLs. They are, in fact, truly "NULL columns" as in "columns containing all NULLLs".

Comment: @ErikE - Thanks, thats what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each one is different. The number of columns in a table does not matter when you are selecting from a table for the queries that you have provided. See the difference of each query for yourself.

1. SELECT null, null, *, null FROM items;

   [Click here to see the output](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/593cf/8/0)
2. SELECT null, null, null, null FROM items;

   [Click here to see the output](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/593cf/2/0)
3. SELECT * FROM items;

   [Click here to see the output](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/593cf/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

The First query  will display the same number of records as in your table. But the values will be replaced by null value in the select query.

```
SELECT null, null, null, null FROM items
```

This is similar to

```
SELECT 5, 5, 5, 5 FROM items
```

The second query,

```
SELECT * FROM items
```

Diplays row with Values.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mahmoud's answer, I can explain one situation when you would need a SELECT NULL.

Assume you have 2 tables, t1 with 3 columns and t2 with 4 columns. And you decide to write a query with UNION involving these tables.

```
SELECT * FROM   t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM   t2
```

The above query will not work since number of columns are different in each table and as such, a union operation cannot be performed by the SQL engine. To overcome this, you would select a null column from t1 and handle it correctly in your app code when accessing the query result set.

```
SELECT *, null FROM   t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM   t2
```

Now both the individual queries above will have 4 columns and thus result in a successful UNION operation.

**That said, the same query will work fine if using UNION ALL since it will automatically add NULLS to the result set if the number of columns are different.**

I know the example does not make much sense but I hope you understand the point of using nulls.